# Is it possible to dynamically control the location of a textbox in excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I working on a dashboard project where I will have three values: min value, max value and current value.  The min and max values will be the end-points of a bar and I'd like to place a text box containing the current value at the appropriate location along the bar.  See below:

Is it possible to do this in Excel and if so, how would I go about achieving this.  I have some experience with Visual Basic, but I haven't come across this one before.

[image]

Ultimately, I am attempting to do an excel version of the dashboard at the following link:

[Link to Dashboard](http://www.russell.com/helping-advisors/markets/EconomicIndicatorsDashboard.aspx)

Comment: Is the bar just a drawn shape?

Comment: A textbox object will have a `top` and `left` value, which you should be able to use to control the object's position relative to the worksheet, or relative to another shape/object, depending on how it has been created.

Comment: Right now, the bar is just a drawn shape. Ultimately, I'd like to make the bar more dynamic too.  I'm actually trying to simulate a dashboard that I find useful. See above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your idea therefore I checked how could the complete code looks like. Here is the result:

```
Sub SolutionShape(currentVal)

Dim shpBar As Shape, shpCurrent As Shape

'let's assume we have only two shapes on the Activesheet
Set shpBar = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)
Set shpCurrent = ActiveSheet.Shapes(2)

Dim barMin As Double, barMax As Double
    barMin = 0.51              'both values could be taken from sheet
    barMax = 6.75

'let's do it visualy complicated this time :)
With shpCurrent
    .Left = (-.Width / 2 + shpBar.Left) + _
        (((currentVal - barMin) / (barMax - barMin)) * shpBar.Width)

    **'EDITED- adding information about current value:**
    .TextFrame.Characters.Text = currentVal
End With

End Sub
```

Call the procedure from event of from immediate window for test, eg.:

```
SolutionShape 0.51      'go to beginning
SolutionShape 6.75      'go to end
```

This solution will work wherever you place shapes and whatever new dimensions of them you set.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm going to try to follow what you did right now. Thanks again.

Comment: Interesting, I did it as a function and it really works well. I just have to figure out how to handle more shapes. The dashboard I'm trying to build will probably have 20 or so. Thanks again, this is a great solution.

Comment: What I can suggest you is to use `.Name` property of each shape in the sheet. After all it would be quite easy to work with them if you call `ActiveSheet.Shapes("barDebt")`, `ActiveSheet.Shapes("curDebt")` instead of `Activesheet.Shapes(1)`, `Activesheet.Shapes(2)`, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Turn on the macro recording when the Shape-object is not selected. Now select it and change its position. Stop recording and use the code generated.

It looks useful to me when I tried it. I got some IncrementTop and IncrementLeft code. You can also use the Top and Left property directly.

It might be an idea to change the name of the Shape-object into something meaningful (in the address box left of the formula box) so your code gets more readable.

So for my Shape named PositionIndicator:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("PositionIndicator").Left = 250
```

Or

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("PositionIndicator").Left = _ 
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("PositionIndicator").Left + 5
```

To link it to a cell value just use `Range("CELLADDRESS").Value2`

To apply it every time you change the cells values use:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Here your script to check if the change concerns one of your input cells and then run the code to change the location of the Shape-object
End Sub
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks.  I like the idea of using the record function to get a start on this. Many thanks.

Comment: using the record function is very often a nice starting point when you dont know exactly what to do. The trick thereafter is to turn that code into a useful one for your exact purpose!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the progress bar is a shape on your worksheet (index 1) and textbox is shape index 2; the following moves the textbox along the progress bar based on the % complete.

Note: It will have to be adjusted to offset the portion of the textbox shape that is to the left of the arrow head.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub movebox()

    Dim textbox As Shape, progbar As Shape
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim stp As Integer, endp As Integer
    Dim tbdyn As Integer
    Dim mn As Double, mx As Double, actper As Double, cur As Double
    Dim admn As Double, admx As Double

    Set ws = Sheets("sheet1")
    Set progbar = ws.Shapes(1)
    Set textbox = ws.Shapes(2)

'// Far left of progress bar position
    stp = progbar.Left
'// Far right of progress bar position
    endp = (progbar.Width + stp)

'// Adjust for starting at 0.51
'// You could adjust mn,mx and cur to take the values
'// from the appropriate cells on the spreadsheet
    mn = 0.51
    mx = 6.07
    admn = 0
    admx = 6.07 - mn
    cur = 4
'// Calculate percentage complete
    actper = cur / admx
'// Apply percentage to progress bar
    tbdyn = actper * endp
'// Move the textox appropriately
    textbox.Left = tbdyn

End Sub
```